# Collaborative online code editor sets infinite loop on firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to build a collaborative online code editor. Where I want to update all screen other than the one who made change each time a change is made in code editor.

The objective is to :

[code editor]

- onchange -> save the value in Firebase

Firebase:

- on change(i.e onValue listener): update the code editor value

But when I use the onValue listener for the firebase an infinite loop sets in. How can I fix it ?

There are two main files :

-Landing.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import CodeEditorWindow from "./CodeEditorWindow";
import axios from "axios";
import { classnames } from "../utils/general";
import { languageOptions } from "../constants/languageOptions";

import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import { defineTheme } from "../lib/defineTheme";
import useKeyPress from "../hooks/useKeyPress";
import OutputWindow from "./OutputWindow";
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput";
import OutputDetails from "./OutputDetails";
import ThemeDropdown from "./ThemeDropdown";
import LanguagesDropdown from "./LanguagesDropdown";

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref,onValue } from "firebase/database";


const javascriptDefault = `/**
* Problem: Binary Search: Search a sorted array for a target value.
*/

// Time: O(log n)
const binarySearch = (arr, target) => {
 return binarySearchHelper(arr, target, 0, arr.length - 1);
};

const binarySearchHelper = (arr, target, start, end) => {
 if (start > end) {
   return false;
 }
 let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
 if (arr[mid] === target){ 
   return mid;
 }
 if (arr[mid] < target) {
   return binarySearchHelper(arr, target, mid + 1, end);
 }
 if (arr[mid] > target) {
   return binarySearchHelper(arr, target, start, mid - 1);
 }
};

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const target = 5;
console.log(binarySearch(arr, target));
`;

const Landing = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState(javascriptDefault);
  const [customInput, setCustomInput] = useState("");
  const [outputDetails, setOutputDetails] = useState(null);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(null);
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("cobalt");
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(languageOptions[0]);

  const enterPress = useKeyPress("Enter");
  const ctrlPress = useKeyPress("Control");

  const onSelectChange = (sl) => {
    console.log("selected Option...", sl);
    setLanguage(sl);
  };

  const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xyz",
  authDomain: "xyz.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xyz-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xyz",
  storageBucket: "xyz.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "94230328",
  appId: "1:907394230328:web:74604ad262f6decb171ecd"
};
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getDatabase(app);

  onValue(ref(db, 'Content/' + language),(snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    if (data) {   
     setCode(data);
    }
  });

  const checkStatus = useCallback(async (token) => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url:  process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_URL + "/" + token,
      params: { base64_encoded: "true", fields: "*" },
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_HOST,
        "X-RapidAPI-Key":  process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
      },
    };
    try {
      let response = await axios.request(options);
      let statusId = response.data.status?.id;

      // Processed - we have a result
      if (statusId === 1 || statusId === 2) {
        // still processing
        setTimeout(() => {
          checkStatus(token);
        }, 2000);
        return;
      } else {
        setProcessing(false);
        setOutputDetails(response.data);
        showSuccessToast(`Compiled Successfully!`);
        console.log("response.data", response.data);
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      setProcessing(false);
      showErrorToast();
    }
  }, []);


  const handleCompile = useCallback(() => {
    setProcessing(true);
    const formData = {
      language_id: language.id,
      // encode source code in base64
      source_code: btoa(code),
      stdin: btoa(customInput),
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_URL,
      params: { base64_encoded: "true", fields: "*" },
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_HOST,
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY,
      },
      data: formData,
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("res.data", response.data);
        const token = response.data.token;
        checkStatus(token);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        let error = err.response ? err.response.data : err;
        // get error status
        let status = err.response.status;
        console.log("status", status);
        if (status === 429) {
          console.log("too many requests", status);

          showErrorToast(
            `Quota of 100 requests exceeded for the Day! Please read the blog on freeCodeCamp to learn how to setup your own RAPID API Judge0!`,
            10000
          );
        }
        setProcessing(false);
        console.log("catch block...", error);
      });
  }, [checkStatus, code, customInput, language.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enterPress && ctrlPress) {
      console.log("enterPress", enterPress);
      console.log("ctrlPress", ctrlPress);
      handleCompile();
    }
  }, [ctrlPress, enterPress, handleCompile]);

  const onChange = (action, data) => {
    switch (action) {
      case "code": {
        setCode(data);
        break;
      }
      default: {
        console.warn("case not handled!", action, data);
      }
    }
  };

  function handleThemeChange(th) {
    const theme = th;
    console.log("theme...", theme);

    if (["light", "vs-dark"].includes(theme.value)) {
      setTheme(theme);
    } else {
      defineTheme(theme.value).then((_) => setTheme(theme));
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    defineTheme("oceanic-next").then((_) =>
      setTheme({ value: "oceanic-next", label: "Oceanic Next" })
    );
  }, []);

  const showSuccessToast = (msg) => {
    toast.success(msg || `Compiled Successfully!`, {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 1000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
    });
  };
  const showErrorToast = (msg, timer) => {
    toast.error(msg || `Something went wrong! Please try again.`, {
      position: "top-right",
      autoClose: timer ? timer : 1000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={2000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
      />
      
      <div className="h-4 w-full bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 via-red-500 to-yellow-500"></div>
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className="px-4 py-2">
          <LanguagesDropdown onSelectChange={onSelectChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="px-4 py-2">
          <ThemeDropdown handleThemeChange={handleThemeChange} theme={theme} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row space-x-4 items-start px-4 py-4">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full justify-start items-end">
          <CodeEditorWindow
            code={code}
            onChange={onChange}
            language={language?.value}
            theme={theme.value}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="right-container flex flex-shrink-0 w-[30%] flex-col">
          <OutputWindow outputDetails={outputDetails} />
          <div className="flex flex-col items-end">
            <CustomInput
              customInput={customInput}
              setCustomInput={setCustomInput}
            />
            <button
              onClick={handleCompile}
              disabled={!code}
              className={classnames(
                "mt-4 border-2 border-black z-10 rounded-md shadow-[5px_5px_0px_0px_rgba(0,0,0)] px-4 py-2 hover:shadow transition duration-200 bg-white flex-shrink-0",
                !code ? "opacity-50" : ""
              )}
            >
              {processing ? "Processing..." : "Compile and Execute"}
            </button>
          </div>
          {outputDetails && <OutputDetails outputDetails={outputDetails} />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Landing;
```

-CodeEditor.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, set, get } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xyz",
  authDomain: "xyz.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xyz-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xyz",
  storageBucket: "xyz.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "94230328",
  appId: "1:907394230328:web:74604ad262f6decb171ecd"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);



const CodeEditorWindow = ({ onChange, language, code, theme }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(code || "");


  const handleEditorChange = (value) => {
    get(ref(db, 'Content/' + language)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        if(snapshot.val() !== value){
          set(ref(db, 'Content/' + language), {
            code: value
          });
          setValue(value);
          onChange("code", value);
        }
        else{
          setValue(value);
          onChange("not", value);
        }


      } else {
        set(ref(db, 'Content/' + language), {
          code: value
        });
        setValue(value);
        onChange("code", value);
      }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="overlay rounded-md overflow-hidden w-full h-full shadow-4xl">
      <Editor
        height="85vh"
        width={`100%`}
        language={language || "javascript"}
        value={value}
        theme={theme}
        defaultValue="// some comment"
        onChange={handleEditorChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default CodeEditorWindow;
```

Comment: Do you really need to listen for live updates? If not, then try getting the value only once using get().

Comment: I do need to listen to live updates as I want the editor to be updated each time a change happens.

Answer (score 0):

In the `handleEditorChange` compare the new contents of the editor and the last value you got from the database. Only write to the database when they are different.

In general, you'll want to also consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for this as there may be multiple users making changes around the same time. To allow concurrent updates to the documents, you'll need a concurrent editing solution such as the one [Firepad](https://firepad.io/) uses.

Comment: I am already comparing the editor change to database content but still, the infinite loop persists. At the moment I was trying if I could somehow reflect the changes back in editor and later could focus on concurrent changes happening.

Comment: You're loading from the database before you check for equality, and then always call `setValue`. That's precisely where your endless loop comes from. You need to keep the value you got from the database, and perform the comparison*before* loading from the database.

Comment: I will have to get that data first before comparing and that's what I am doing in the codeeditor file. And if there is no data or it is not the same then I use the 'set' to change to the database. How will I compare before getting the data from the database?

Comment: You have to indeed get the data first, but you don't have to get it every time. Instead use an `onValue` listener *outside* of `handleEditorChange` to listen for updates, and set those to the state and to a variable. Then inside `handleEditorChange` check the variable from the database against the new value from the editor.

Comment: I am not using a onValue inside the handleEditorChange, I am using a get bcz handle editor gets called when a change occurs and get allows to load data just once. i was using onValue in the landing.js to listen to database change and update. I have just started with javascript as well so please direct me on how the code changes would be bcz get gives the data just once right and i need it to be load once everytime a change happens inprder to check. Could you demostrate with the code changes that would make it easy to understand.